# default value of variable in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
var one = 0;
var two = 0;

$scope.one= $scope.myData[0];
$scope.two= $scope.myData[1];
```

myData is json file so var one is been set to for example 15 and it work properly. I was surprised that my {{two}} didn't display zero. $scope.myData[1] is not yet exist, but why it doesn't set to 0 as I initialize it to zero previously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialization is not in scope.

You must initialize variables in this way:

```js
$scope.one = 0;
$scope.two = 0;

// Your other code;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it so:

```
$scope.$watch('myData', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    $scope.one = newValue && newValue[0] || 0;
    $scope.two = newValue && newValue[1] || 0;
});
```